# Angular UI Router - Params value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Check Below code,

```
.state('abcd.efgr', {
   url: /test/url?param1&param2&param3,
   params: {
    param1: {
     value: 'defaultValue1',
     squash: true
    },
    param2: {
     value: 'defaultValue1',
     squash: true
    }  
  }
});
```

When I do

```
 $state.go(abcd.efgr, {param1: '123', param2: '124', param3: '125'});
```

All the parameters in url of the state would set to above values respectively.
Now the thing is,

> 1.) I need to hide these params from url.
>
> 2.) The Url will come from server side, so can't send them as a part of params, which many of the post suggest.
>
> 3.) For using squash, the value ('defaultValue1', 'defaultValue2') must to equal to the their value in URL.
>
> 4.) The problem is the defaultValues are dynamic so can't set one value.
>
> 5.) How can I use squash technique with dynamic value and if not squash what can I do different to achieve hiding of params from URL and using them in my respective controller of the state.